# Re arranging a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to do some DNA analysis in C++.
I have a 2D array of characters containing DNA sequences. `char input[n][m];`

Now based on the DNA pattern, I do some processing on the input array and find a new sequence for this pattern.

Let say the original sequence was `1,2,3,4,5,6`. These are the 6 DNA's (rows of the 2D array)

After processing i get the order as `1,6,2,4,3,5`. Then how do I rearrange the original input array as per this sequence. That is, the first row of input should now have 1st DNA, 2nd row should now have the DNA which was sixth in the original array and so on.

```
 int main()

{

using namespace std;
char input[t][l] = {    {'A','A','A','T','C','A','G','T','A'},
                        {'A','T','T','A','C','T','G','C','A'},
                        {'A','G','C','T','A','C','T','G','C'},
                        {'A','T','T','A','C','T','G','C','A'},
                        {'A','G','C','T','A','C','T','G','C'}


                 };

// SOME PROCESSING

Here output array has the elements ={1,6,2,4,3,5}

  for (int i = 0; i<t; i++)
  {
  cout << output[i] << " ";
  }  
}
```

Any ideas how to change the addresses in the memory so as re-order the original array?

Comment: C++ offers ordered collection classes which are far more flexible than the low-level array construct.  Is there a specific reason you are not using `vector` or similar?  http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html

Comment: Well, This is a part of a code of about 50k lines.
So I need to make changes in the original array itself.
Actually I need to pass this re ordered array to another algorithm for processing.

Comment: What I'm asking is why not have each of your lines stored as an object (say, `class DnaSequence`)...then have a vector of pointers to these objects.  Your reorganization would then simply reorder the pointers, and it would be able to do this quickly even if the DNA sequences were long.  By the way, if you are hyper-concerned about storage space of radix 4 elements (or even if you have some other states like "unknown") you might find my Nstate library interesting: http://hostilefork.com/nstate/

Answer (score 1):

This would only move around pointers:

```
char input[5][9] = {    {'A','A','A','T','C','A','G','T','A'},
                        {'A','T','T','A','C','T','G','C','A'},
                        {'A','G','C','T','A','C','T','G','C'},
                        {'A','T','T','A','C','T','G','C','A'},
                        {'A','G','C','T','A','C','T','G','C'}
                 };

char* output[5];
output[0] = input[3];
output[1] = input[2];
output[2] = input[4];

char test = output[1][3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do it in place, just create new destination matrix, copy row 1 to 1, row 6 to row 2, and so on... 
Just use output[i] as index for row of original matrix.

With some more bookkeeping, it can certainly also be done in place.
Ok, if you need in-place, I'd do something like this:
You have your pair list of [source row][destination row], like:

[1]<-[1],
[2]<-[6],
[3]<-[2],
...

Create map describing this copy operations. Then just start from 1.

[1]<-[1] is easy. (You can remove it from map)

[2]<-[6] overwrites your original row 2, which you need in next step. So you exchange rows 2 and 6. Now row 6 is in right place, but you need to change mapping. You need to change mapping [3]<-[2] to [3]<-[6] using something like like map[2]=6.

And so on, until done.

Comment: Or you can use std::swap() for matrix with small size, but it exchanges values not the pointers.

Comment: But then I would also need to copy back all the content from the new matrix to the original one. That is the last option. I am looking for something more efficient as the data size is too large and hence it would take too long.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use `vector<string> input`

and then

```
vector<double> output_list (t,0); // length t, initialized to 0

// assign the values of output_list

for (int i = 0; i<t; i++)
{
cout << input[output_list[i]] << " ";
}
```

Please note that this solution does not require additional memory (there is not a second 2D array) nor additional computation time (you do not swap the data, you simply call the part that you need)

If you instead absolutely need to re-order the array (as I notice in your comments), you may `swap(input[i],input[j])` as many times as needed.